Is it possible to use server-side rendering in Vue to have an external job scheduler pull a page in a certain state and save a PDF of it?
I have been asked to add functionality for users of a web application to automate sending a snapshot of the application with the given day's data on a daily basis. Is it possible to use Vue's SSR to access the application as a particular user via a scheduled task run on Airflow or something similar, so that that user's visual config and data view preferences are reflected, and to export that view to PDF and save it somewhere?
I have been looking into this but am new to Vue and feel like I'm running in circles. I'm not sure if this is a reasonable request or if I should suggest just accessing the same data with the scheduler and putting it into a bespoke e-mail template that looks different than the application itself.

It's unclear what's your case exactly but looks like the case for headless browser. Vue ssr doesn't have DOM
